# Mudança de Diretório Matlab

Tags: matlab

Gostaria de saber como soluciono este problema; Estou usando um bloco de função dentro do Simulink, no entanto quando clico em executar meu código aparece o seguinte erro:

The current directory 'c:\program files\matlab\matlab production server\r2015a\bin' is reserved for MATLAB files.

Please change your current directory to a writeable directory outside of the MATLAB installation area.
Component: Stateflow | Category: General error

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a solucionar este problema ?

obs: Sou novo aqui e bem inexperiente em linguagens de programação, me desculpem se não fui tão claro em minha duvida.

Answer (score -1):

Isso é normal conforme o que se deseja fazer no Matlab.

Caso você não tenha nenhum script ou algo assim, mude o diretório do matlab na interface mesmo, seja tal qual "unix" diretamente no prompt de comando (`cd C:\Users\SEU_NOME`) ou então com o mouse mesmo.
Acima seu nome é seu diretório padrão do windows, mas talvez use algum outro diretório que você criou juntamente com seu respectivo caminho (por exemplo `C:\MEUS_TESTES\TESTE1`).

Caso a sua simulacão dependa de scripts e arquivos que você criou, transfira estes arquivos para o diretório que você deseja rodar, mude o diretório no matlab (Matlab faz isso automaticamente dependendo de como você abre e roda os arquivos) e comece a rodar a partir de lá. Cuidado com dependência que você possa ter criado, tal qual rodar simulações e pedir pra escrever em um diretório especifico ou chamar um arquivo pelo caminho inteiro.

Um ponto importante, Matlab chama automaticamente as funcões da biblioteca dele, porém outras funcões ou scripts que tenham sido criados devem estar no mesmo diretório que está sendo rodado ou então em alguma pasta que esteja no `path` do matlab. 
O `path` é uma lista de diretórios que um sistema irá procura por programas automaticamente.
O Matlab tem seu próprio `path` que deixa disponivel suas bibliotecas, ele pode ser alterado nas configuracões. Não recomendo ficar alterando o `path` por qualquer coisa, pois suas funcões podem ter preferencia sobre funcões de mesmo nome da biblioteca do matlab, e no futuro isso pode dar problemas.

Caso isso não tenha solucionado, deixe comentários que posso tentar ver qual o problema.

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema, amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: @FelipeVieira De nada, neste caso, se a resposta está de acordo com o que você quer, pense em aceitar ela, afinal este é uma das ideias do stackoverflow! Caso não seja o que você quer, esteja livre a fazer mais comentários ou editar a pergunta.  :D